# Import and render an html element with SolidJS

Tags: javascript, html, solid-js

When my application loads, it will call the backend to obtain a description of components the user decides to add.

These objects should have a function to generate their html, take a button for example: it will export an html() method that returns a string containing an HTML text:

```
const buttonText = "I'm a button"
export default {
  html() {
    return `<button>${buttonText}</button>`
  }
}
```

On the frontend side, I will be using import statement to load the aforementioned button module and store it in a JSON object, sort of like a plugins manager.

When it comes time to render it, I tried using Dynamic:

```
<For each={plugins()} fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>{ plugin =>
  <div>
    <Dynamic component={plugin.module.html()}>
    </Dynamic>
  <div>
}</For>
```

But it falls with `DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<button>I'm a button</button>') is not a valid name.`

Which makes sense since it is expecting something like a `"div"` element, not a string like `<button>I'm a button</button>`.

What would be the correct way to render HTML strings in SolidJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be just to use `innerHTML` like so:

```
<For each={plugins()} fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
{ plugin =>
 <div innerHTML={plugin.module.html()}>
 <div>
}</For>
```

If you need something more interactive, perhaps using `template` and `cloneNode` which is what Solidjs compiles your code to normally.
Here is a full example below. [I created it on the playground](https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-715126058&version=1.4.1).

```
import { render, template } from "solid-js/web";
import { For } from "solid-js";

function MakeButton() {
  const plugins = ["<button>Click me</button>"];

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicked button");
  }

  const createElem = (el: string) => {
    const elem = template(el, 2);
    const ret = elem.cloneNode(true);
    if (ret.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      ret.onclick = handleClick;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  return (<>
    <For each={plugins} fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      {plugin =>
        <div>{createElem(plugin)}</div>
      }
    </For>
  </>);
}

render(() => <MakeButton />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to import a regular HTML element and render it inside a solid component, than answer is simple, just put it between curly brackets like any other expression. Unlike React, Solid can render an HTML element directly.

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

const el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = 'Some Content';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>{el}</div>
  );
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

You don't need to use innerHTML property or you don't even need to wrap it inside a JSX element:

```js
const el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = 'Some Content';

function App() {
  return el;
}
```

Few issues with your question. The `html` method is not returning an HTML element but a string:

```js
const buttonText = "I'm a button"
export default {
  html() {
    return `<button>${buttonText}</button>`
  }
}
```

You can fix it by returning an actual Element. I called the imported object x in order to avoid code bloat since you can import any variable from another module:

```
const buttonText = "I'm a button";

const x = {
  html() {
    const el = document.createElement("button");
    el.innerText = buttonText;
    return el;
  },
};

function App() {
  return x.html();
}
```

If you are using x just to return a string, you may omit it completely and just export the element itself:

```
const el = document.createElement("button");
el.innerText = buttonText;

export default el;
```

As an alternative you can return the string and have the DOM render for you using `innerHTML` property. You can either create the element yourself:

```js
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = x.html();
```

Or have Solid do it for you:

```js
const txt = "<button>I'm a button</button>";

function App() {
  return <div innerHTML={txt}></div>
}
```

Either way it has nothing to do with Solid, it is browser's feature to render a string into HTML element when assigned to an element's innerHTML. Actually it is what Solid's `template` function use internally.

As a side note, Solid uses clone method to render multiple elements efficiently, if you are not rendering large HTML text with with lots of elements, `createElement` is better since it is cleaner and faster.

"Loading components dynamically" refers to something totally different, so does a component. A dynamic component means the rendered output is bound to a variable rather than a condition:

```
const RedThing = () => <strong style="color: red">Red Thing</strong>;
const GreenThing = () => <strong style="color: green">Green Thing</strong>;
const BlueThing = () => <strong style="color: blue">Blue Thing</strong>;

const [selected, setSelected] = createSignal('red');

const options = {
  red: RedThing,
  green: GreenThing,
  blue: BlueThing
}

<Dynamic component={options[selected()]} />
```

Still you need to pass a component, not a string. A string containing a valid HTML text is not a JSX component.

It is best to express our problems in simple terms and avoid technical jargon because it makes really hard to understand.